# C# sort list in alphabetical order

Tags: c#

How can I sort a list of users by last name in the formats below?

first.last

first.mi.last

```
mylist.Sort();
```

sorts by first name, and that is not what i want to do. Do I somehow need to use a RegEx?

Comment: What's in your list?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Linq` to order your users:

```
using System.Linq;
mylist.OrderBy(x => x.LastName);
```

If you have same last names you can order users by middle name. If you have same middle names you can order users by first name:

```
mylist.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.MiddleName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName);
```

Comment: My list is defined as List<string> mylist = new List<string>(); . Do I need to change the way it is defined?

Comment: @Dawn555 Yes.  You will need the list to be of some type that has the properties `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `MiddleName`.  The string type will not work for this.

Comment: @Dawn555 Yes, you should create a `User` class with 3 properties: `LastName`, `MiddleName` and `FirstName`. And then you should create `List<User> mylist = new List<User>();`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your names are simple strings (and not objects with FirstName and LastName properties) like this:

```
var list = new List<string> { "c.a", "a.c" , "b"};
```

you can order them like this:

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(item => item.Split('.').Last());
```

Output:

```
c.a 
b 
a.c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort *in place*, try specifing the comparer

```
 mylist.Sort((left, right) => string.Compare(left.LastName, right.LastName));
```

In case `mylist` contains `string` items, you have to extract `LastName`:

```
 private static String LastName(string value) {
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     return value;

   int p = value.LastIndexOf('.');

   return value.SubString(p + 1);  
 } 

 ...

 mylist.Sort((left, right) => string.Compare(LastName(left), LastName(right)));
```